# How to install a distro from DVD?

Tags: boot, grub2, dvd

I know this maybe dumb, but I forgot how to do that in Ubuntu. I wanted to try Ubuntu 16.04 Beta 1 and I burned DVD but when I saw that grub doesn't see my DVD so how to install it? Maybe I missed some steps - I didn't change distro for a while so yeah. If it helps - I have Ubuntu 15.10 now. Also my notebook is Asus so I go to Grub pressing F10.

Comment: Just to clarify, did you mean your BIOS and not grub. Also make the DVD the top priority for boot-up in your BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell your computer to boot from the DVD.

Press F12 at boot (before grub). Choose the DVD.

(It can be something different like F2 etc)